# SELECT REPLACE and save the replacement changes MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace all '-' in my column but I don't know how to combined SET and REPLACE. Please respond with what my SQL query should look like.

[image: MYSQL SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Looks good to me. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to use the `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE ldr.client_order
SET waybill = REPLACE(waybill, '-', '')
WHERE INSTR(waybill, '-') > 0
```

The `WHERE` clause you can use to update only those entries had the `-`. If you are avoid the `WHERE` clause it will update for all the entries.

Comment: WHERE clause here is redundant and just slows down query execution.